# Android and SharedPreferences on an independent class

Tags: android, class, sharedpreferences

I'm starting to programming for Android and I hadn't had any serious problems until I tried to separate the reading/writing code of SharedPreferences (on each activity) to a separate class, say ConfigManager.

Here is my ConfigManager class:

```
package com.application.testing;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class ConfigManager extends Activity {

    public boolean boolPref;
    public String stringPref;

    private SharedPreferences prefs;

    public ConfigManager() {
        prefs = getSharedPreferences(
                getResources().getString(R.string.preferences),
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        loadCfg();
    }

    public void saveCfg() {

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

        editor.putBoolean("boolPreference", boolPref);
        editor.putString("stringPreference", stringPref);

        editor.commit();

    }

    public void loadCfg() {

        this.boolPref = prefs.getBoolean("boolPreference", false);
        this.stringPref = prefs.getString("stringPreference", "");

    }

}
```

Now, when I try to instantiate this class to read/write preferences, I receive error and the application exits.

Let's say a splashscreen, if the user decides not to show, I keep it in a preference, and on the start of the application I read if it's true or false, to show the splashscreen or move to the next activity.

This would be the splashscreen class code:

```
package com.application.testing;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    public ConfigManager cfg;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        cfg = new ConfigManager();

        if (!(cfg.boolPref)) {
            Intent i = new Intent("com.application.testing.NEXTACTIVITY");
            startActivity(i);
        } else {

            setContentView(R.layout.splash);

            Thread timer = new Thread() {
                public void run() {

                    try {
                        sleep(3000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        Intent i = new Intent("com.application.testing.NEXTACTIVITY");
                        startActivity(i);
                    }

                }
            };

            timer.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        cfg.saveCfg(); // not neccesary, no preference changes during splashscreen execution
        finish();
    }

}
```

Finally, this is Logcat output:

```
12-21 23:46:48.294: D/AndroidRuntime(1381): Shutting down VM
12-21 23:46:48.344: W/dalvikvm(1381): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
12-21 23:46:48.375: E/AndroidRuntime(1381): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-21 23:46:48.375: E/AndroidRuntime(1381): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.application.testing/com.application.testing.SplashScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-21 23:46:48.375: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
12-21 23:46:48.375: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
12-21 23:46:48.375: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
12-21 23:46:48.375: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
12-21 23:46:48.375: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-21 23:46:48.375: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-21 23:46:48.375: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-21 23:46:48.375: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-21 23:46:48.375: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-21 23:46:48.375: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-21 23:46:48.375: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-21 23:46:48.375: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-21 23:46:48.375: E/AndroidRuntime(1381): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-21 23:46:48.375: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:80)
12-21 23:46:48.375: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at com.application.testing.ConfigManager.<init>(ConfigManager.java:22)
12-21 23:46:48.375: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at com.application.testing.SplashScreen.onCreate(SplashScreen.java:22)
12-21 23:46:48.375: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-21 23:46:48.375: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
12-21 23:46:48.375: E/AndroidRuntime(1381):     ... 11 more
```

Does anyone know where my error is?

A lot of thanks in advance, because I'm going crazy :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. There is no need to mark a question as solved in the title. The "icon/box" left to the question will turn green once you receive an answer or more, and the font will turn yellow once you accept an answer. So everyone can see the question status anyway. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ConfigManager` should not extend `Activity`. Instead, change its constructor to take a `Context`:

```
public ConfigManager(Context context) {
    prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(
            context.getResources().getString(R.string.preferences),
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    loadCfg();
}
```

You can then pass the `Activity` to `ConfigManager` in the `onCreate` of `SplashScreen`:

```
cfg = new ConfigManager(this);
```

Comment: Right! That was it! I just want to point a thing, add `context.` to `getSharedPreferences()`